# How to get VieBag Data in Google Map Using javascript and ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

With My Code I deserialized Json object for a city includes Tourist places. Each Tourist Places there are Name, Shor-Text, GeoCo-ordinates and Image. IN my controller class I deserialize all of this object and put all of this data in ViewBag.Now this portion is ok So far. My code to get The name and json deserilization in Controller class is as follows-

```
 public ActionResult Index(City objCityModel)
    {
        string name = objCityModel.Name;
        return View();
    }
 public ActionResult GoogleMap(City objCityModel)
    {
        string name = objCityModel.Name;
        ViewBag.Title = name;

        var ReadJson = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath(@"~/App_Data/POI_Json/" + name + ".json"));

        RootObject json = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<RootObject>(ReadJson);
        List<Poi> mycities = new List<Poi>();

        foreach (var item in json.poi)
        {
            Poi obj = new Poi()
            {
                Name = item.Name,
                Shorttext = item.Shorttext,
                GeoCoordinates = item.GeoCoordinates,
                Images = item.Images,

            };
            mycities.Add(obj);
        }

        ViewBag.Cities = mycities;

        return View();

    }
```

I create a search box to get the name to go to the google map view. I am giving this code just for understanding-

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("GoogleMap", "Home"))
   {
    <div class="wrapper wrapper-content">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)
        <label for="somevalue">City Name</label>

        <div class="input-group-btn">
            <button id="mapViewBtn" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Map View</button>
            }
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Now My problem is in the GoogleMap view. I am getting how to use all of my View bag data in this google map. I use the below link to write my code. Well I am trying in my way but could no succeed. I only want to use Javascript not the Ajax. But This is not working at all. My code is as follows-

**Modified Code**

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<title>GoogleMap</title>
 <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"    type="text/javascript"></script>


<style>
 #map_canvas img{max-width:none}
 </style>

 <style>
 .infoDiv {
 height: 200px;    
 width: 300px; 
 -webkit-user-select: none; 
 background-color: white; 
 }
 </style>


   <div id="map_canvas" style="height: 600px;"></div>


    @section scripts {
        <section class="scripts">

    <script type="text/javascript">


        $(document).ready(function () {
            Initialize();
        });


         function Initialize() {


        google.maps.visualRefresh = true;
        var @ViewBag.Title = new google.maps.LatLng(53.408841, -2.981397);


        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 14,
            center: Liverpool,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.G_NORMAL_MAP
        };


    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);


    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(53.40091, -2.994464);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlng,
        map: map,
        title: 'Tate Gallery'
    });


    marker.setIcon('http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png')

    var cities = JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.Cities))');

       $.each(cities , function(index, obj){

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            'position': new google.maps.LatLng(item.GeoLong, item.GeoLat),
            'map': map,
            'title':obj.Name
        });




        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: "<div class='infoDiv'><h2>" + 
              item.Name + "</h2>" + "<div><h4>Opening hours: " + 
              item.ShortText + "</h4></div></div>"
        });


        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        });

     })
   }


  </script>
  </section>
  }
```

Comment: you want to use a viewbag data in a javascript variable??

Comment: @Reddy Yes . I want to use my all view bag data from controller to javascript.

Comment: I'll give you my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Convert `ViewBag` which contains `list of poi` into json array using `@Html.Raw and Json.Encode` and then loop thru the array using.

```
<script>
 var cities = JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.Cities))');
 $.each(cities , function(index, obj){
    //here obj contains the POI information
    console.log(obj.GeoCoordinates);
 });
</script>
```

Comment: Could you please explain a little bit more I am very new in handling this case. Thank you very much. Could you also please tell me in which place in my code Should I use it.

Comment: @AntonyInn you have to use `$.each(ViewBag.Cities, function (i, item)` here.i have updated the answer also

Comment: I have modified my question but everything is gone. Now nothing is shown in the view

Comment: @AntonyInn any console errro

Answer (score 0):

First convert your c# object to Json like below.

Write this in your cshtml page on top

```
   @{   
     var jsonData = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ViewBag.Cities);
    }
```

Then inside your script block you can do this.

```
<script>
      var citiesList= JSON.parse(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(jsonData)));
      alert(citiesList);
  </script>
```

let me know if you have any issues

Comment: Could you please explain a littole bit more. Shoud I use your code before the Javascript.

Comment: I modified my code in the Question. But The Google map view is gone and nothing is shown

Comment: what are you getting in the alert??

Comment: I am getting error Could not find file 'I:\PoiFinder\PoiFinder\PoiFinder\App_Data\POI_Json\.json'. in line Line 74:             var ReadJson = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath(@"~/App_Data/POI_Json/" + name + ".json"));

Comment: So you are getting this in the alert?? I dont think this has anything to do with my code..

Comment: It Is Strange that same data I am using in another view it is working. But if I try to use in google view it is not working.

Comment: might be something with your code in this view. Debug line by line and see the values. Also the error says that it cant find a file and it is trying to find a file with the name `.json` without the filename. See whats causing it